# Debugging and Solving Software Problems - Google X Coursera course week 4 qwiklabs

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting, optimization

How do I optimise this script with the recommendations given in the instructions?

> This is a pretty challenging task that you have to complete by modifying the `get_same_or_newer()` function.
> Here are few hints to fix this issue:
>
> - Download the file only once from the URL.
> - Pre-process it so that the same calculation doesn't need to be done over and over again. This can be done in two ways. You can choose any one of them:
>
>   1. To create a dictionary with the start dates and then use the data in the dictionary instead of the complicated calculation.
>   2. To sort the data by `start_date` and then go date by date.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv
import datetime
import requests

FILE_URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/gwg-content/gic215/employees-with-date.csv"


def get_start_date():
    """Interactively get the start date to query for."""


    print()
    print('Getting the first start date to query for.')
    print()
    print('The date must be greater than Jan 1st, 2018')
    year = int(input('Enter a value for the year: '))
    month = int(input('Enter a value for the month: '))
    day = int(input('Enter a value for the day: '))
    print()


    return datetime.datetime(year, month, day)


def get_file_lines(url):
    """Returns the lines contained in the file at the given URL"""


    # Download the file over the internet
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    lines = []


    for line in response.iter_lines():
        lines.append(line.decode("UTF-8"))
    return lines


def get_same_or_newer(start_date):
    """Returns the employees that started on the given date, or the closest one."""
    data = get_file_lines(FILE_URL)
    reader = csv.reader(data[1:])


    # We want all employees that started at the same date or the closest newer
    # date. To calculate that, we go through all the data and find the
    # employees that started on the smallest date that's equal or bigger than
    # the given start date.
    min_date = datetime.datetime.today()
    min_date_employees = []
    for row in reader: 
        row_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[3], '%Y-%m-%d')


        # If this date is smaller than the one we're looking for,
        # we skip this row
        if row_date < start_date:
            continue


        # If this date is smaller than the current minimum,
        # we pick it as the new minimum, resetting the list of
        # employees at the minimal date.
        if row_date < min_date:
            min_date = row_date
            min_date_employees = []


        # If this date is the same as the current minimum,
        # we add the employee in this row to the list of
        # employees at the minimal date.
        if row_date == min_date:
            min_date_employees.append("{} {}".format(row[0], row[1]))


    return min_date, min_date_employees


def list_newer(start_date):
    while start_date < datetime.datetime.today():
        start_date, employees = get_same_or_newer(start_date)
        print("Started on {}: {}".format(start_date.strftime("%b %d, %Y"), employees))


        # Now move the date to the next one
        start_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)


def main():
    start_date = get_start_date()
    list_newer(start_date)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have removed the line 43 in `get_same_or_newer` :
*`data = get_file_lines(FILE_URL)`* so that the url isn't requested in every single iteration of the loop and this has reduced the time it took by half, but I have not optimised completely with the recommendations given.

Answer (score 0):

> - *Download the file only once from the URL.*
> - *Pre-process it so that the same calculation doesn't need to be done over and over again.*

You can either set an extra parameter `data` to `list_newer` and `get_same_or_newer` and pass the processed data every call, or you could just make `data` a global variable that can be used from any function. [**Just make sure to define it before calling any functions that use it.**]

---

> *1. To create a dictionary with the start dates and then use the data in the dictionary instead of the complicated calculation.*

This *will* reduce the search time by a lot, but only if the exact `start_date` exists in `data`, otherwise it can take just as much time as it does currently to find the next `min_date`.

```py
# FILE_URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/gwg-content/gic215/employees-with-date.csv"

def get_file_data(url):
    """Downloads, processes and returns data contained in the file at the given URL""" 

    # Download the file over the internet
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    decoded_lines = [line.decode("UTF-8") for line in response.iter_lines()]

    rows = list(csv.reader(decoded_lines[1:]))
    dates = {row[3] for row in rows} ## unique dates
    getNames = lambda sdate: [f'{r[0]} {r[1]}' for r in rows if r[3]==sdate]
    return {datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d'): getNames(d) for d in dates}
```

Now, you can rewrite `get_same_or_newer` and use it as before

```py
date_employees = get_file_data(FILE_URL)
def get_same_or_newer(start_date, data=date_employees):
    """Returns the employees that started on the given date, or the closest one."""

    ## try to access as dictionary key to immediately find exact date
    min_date, min_date_employees = start_date, data.get(start_date)

    ## no exact match ---> search for next oldest date
    if min_date_employees is None:
        newer_dates = [d for d in data if d>start_date] ## filter
        if newer_dates: 
            min_date = min(newer_dates)
            min_date_employees = data[min_date]
        else: min_date, min_date_employees = datetime.datetime.today(), []
    return min_date, min_date_employees
```

But you could also bypass it entirely in `list_newer`

```py
# date_employees = get_file_data(FILE_URL)
def list_newer(start_date, end_date=datetime.datetime.today(), data=date_employees):
    newer_dates = sorted([d for d in date_employees if start_date<=d<end_date]) # filter+sort
    for d in newer_dates: 
        print(f"Started on {d.strftime('%b %d, %Y')}: {data[d]}")
```

---

> 2. To sort the data by `start_date` and then go date by date.

This can make searching even faster [though there isn't a special advantage for exact matches like with a dictionary], because you can use [binary search](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/binary-search) on sorted data.

```py
def get_file_data(url):
    """Downloads, processes and returns data contained in the file at the given URL""" 

    # Download the file over the internet
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    decoded_lines = [line.decode("UTF-8") for line in response.iter_lines()]

    rows = list(csv.reader(decoded_lines[1:]))
    return [(
        datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d'), 
        [f'{fname} {lname}' for fname,lname,dept,sdate in rows if sdate==d]
    ) for d in sorted({row[3] for row in rows})] # sort set --> build sorted list
```

<sup>I think sets get automatically sorted, but I used the `sorted` function as well just in case.</sup>

The binary search logic is contained in the `bisect_byDate` function, which can reduce `get_same_or_newer` to a single statement. <sup>*(`data[bisect_byDate(start_date)] if start_date < data[-1][0] else....today(), []`*)</sup>

```py
date_employees = get_file_data(FILE_URL)
def bisect_byDate(start_date, data=date_employees):
    '''Find index of date (or next closest) with binary search'''
    lo, hi = 0, len(data)
    while lo < hi: 
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if data[mid][0] < start_date: 
            lo = mid + 1 
        else: hi = mid
    while data[lo-1][0] >= start_date: lo -= 1
    return lo
    
def get_same_or_newer(start_date, data=date_employees):
    """Returns the employees that started on the given date, or the closest one."""

    ## first, check that the latest date isn't before start_date
    if data[-1][0] < start_date: return datetime.datetime.today(), [] 

    return data[bisect_byDate(start_date)]
```

And again, you could bypass `get_same_or_newer` entirely in `list_newer`:

```py
def list_newer(start_date, end_date=datetime.datetime.today(), data=date_employees):
    for sdate, employees in data[bisect_byDate(start_date):]: 
        if not sdate < end_date: break
        print(f"Started on {sdate.strftime('%b %d, %Y')}: {employees}")
```

---

You could combine the advantages of both methods by having the dictionary as well as a sorted list of dates. Then, you could use the dictionary to check for exact matches before using binary search on the sorted dates to find the closest key.